# Memory error in opening arcmap 9.3

Tags: arcgis-9.3, arcgis-runtime, memory

I am working on remorte Desktop where arcGIS 9.3.1 is installed. It was working perfectly for Long time. Currently it shows a funny error like: you do not have enough memmory to run the application and stop before opening arcmap or sometimes stop in the middle of a Tool progress...

Comment: restart the computer?

Comment: The question is *what memory?*, is it RAM, Page File, %SystemDrive%, user quota... best to fix as many as possible. It was running previously so it's not insufficient RAM (after restart) try cleaning up your system drive, especially %TEMP% and %TMP%, and delete your prefetch for this application in case it's been corrupted - don't worry it will get created again next time you run it.